# What does phase of an image means?

Tags: image, image-processing, matlab

What does phase of an image means? In the context of image processing. How do we find it?

Answer (score 3):

This is well described on this webpage: [Magnitude and Phase of Images](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Esastry/ee20/vision2/node6.html)

Basically you perform a Fourier transform and look at the phase of the result.