# Calculate the phase of complex numbers

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have an image represented as a matrix of complex numbers, the size of matrix is `m×m`.

Which one is the right way to calculate a phase of the image?

1. `angle` / `atan2`

   ```
   Img_phase = angle(img);
   ```

   or

   ```
   Img_phase = atan2 ( imag(img),real(img) );
   ```

   or both of them are correct?
2. Do I need to perform Fourier transform before calculating the phase?

   ```
   img_fft = fftshift (fft2 (img) );
   ```

   Then

   ```
   Img_phase = angle(img_fft);
   ```

   or

   ```
   Img_phase = atan2 ( imag(img_fft),real(img_fft) );
   ```
3. If I have more than one image, do I need to normalize the images (dividing  by a max value) before calculating the phase?

[For example these images which represent the outputs of a simulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKIbE.png). More information can be found in [this link](https://www.rp-photonics.com/lp_modes.html)

I have export the outputs to matlab (as matrices of complex numbers) for more processing. First I want to calculate the phase I mentioned before.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does phase of an image means?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644708/what-does-phase-of-an-image-means)

Comment: The phase *of an image* doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Wolfie the provided link doesn't answer my questions.

Comment: @Yves Daoust why?

Comment: An image has a whole spectrum of phases, not a single one. From the content of your question, you seem to have little understanding of the Fourier transform and I wonder how you will use our answers.

Comment: @YvesDaoust  could you please check this [link](http://matlabgeeks.com/tips-tutorials/how-to-do-a-2-d-fourier-transform-in-matlab/)

Comment: I feel like between the link in the question I marked, and the link *you* just provided, you have the method for getting the phase of an image... everything points to Fourier transforms

Comment: @Wolfie why we need to perform Fourier transform before calculating the phase? And what about the normalization?

Answer (score 0):

**`angle` vs `atan2`**

The difference between `atan2(imag(img),real(img))` and `angle(img)` is very clear: there is none. Check the source code of [`angle`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/angle.html):

> ```
> function p = angle(h)
>
> p = atan2(imag(h), real(h));
> ```

So, you do whatever you want, but `angle` may be somewhat easier to understand.

**Do I have to take the fourier transform?**

It depends on the meaning of the image and what you want.

**Should I normalise the image?**

It doesn't matter. The angle does not depend on a real scaling factor, i.e.:

```
angle(1+3i) == angle(5*(1+3i))
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, what do you mean by **"depends on the meaning of the image"?** Could you please give me an example?

Comment: @Shdotcom the responsibility to provide examples is on your shoulders, what is your application of this?

Comment: @Shdotcom I don't know your application and normally I don't work with imaginary images. Maybe the imaginary image is already the fourier transform of another real image? So, it means, I don't know and probably nobody knows it without more information.